# Creating a dataframe with a double loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

Let's say I have `a = 4` and `b = 3`.
I'd like to create a df/tibble `a x b` using a double for-loop, knowing that each values of the df would be a list (that contains values based on `i = 1:4` and `j = 1:3`).

My attempt:

```
df=data_frame()
for (i in 1:a){
  for (j in 1:b){
    df[[i]][[j]]<-list(i,j)
  }
}
```

If you have not-algorithmic answers, I'm also eager to know them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a tibble with three columns, with each entry containing a list of two numbers which would coincide with the column and row numbers:

```
as_tibble(lapply(1:3, function(x) lapply(1:4, function(y) list(x, y))), 
          .name_repair = "unique")
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  ...1       ...2       ...3      
  <list>     <list>     <list>    
1 <list [2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>
2 <list [2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>
3 <list [2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>
4 <list [2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
expand.grid(1:a, 1:b)
```

The example you provide does not need a `for`-loop as most applications in R. So, do you really need the loops? (For example in real life something else happens in the loops which determines that you need them?